# vim how to cut text and insert into a new line

Tags: vim

I want to do this:

```
1 printf("hello world\n");
2 bool func() //I want to cut the comment and insert between line 1 and line 2
3 {
4     //to do
5 }
```

And, I want to cut the comment after `//` and to insert between line 1 and line 2. As I know, by using `Ctrl+v`, `vim` is transformed into `VISUAL` mode, and you can select the text, and by pressing `d`, you can cut the text, but How can I insert the text that be cutted and insert into a new line? Is there any command?

And I think after cutting the text, and you can press `o` and press `esc` and press `p` to paste, but it seems to tedious. Are there any better command?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: 'P' will past before the cursor, and 'p' will past after the cursor.  :h is your friend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to save keystrokes you can insert the `"` register in insert mode by using `<c-r>"`.

Also you can delete from the cursor to the end of the line with `D`, which places the deleted section in the `"` register.

So if your cursor was on the first character of the comment you can use

```
DO<c-r>"
```

to transfrom

```
printf("hello world\n");
bool func() //I want to cut the comment and insert between line 1 and line 2
{
    //to do
}
```

Into

```
printf("hello world\n");
//I want to cut the comment and insert between line 1 and line 2
bool func() 
{
    //to do
}
```

All you have to do is clean up the trailing white space after `func()`.

---

Take a look at `:help i_CTRL-R` to learn more about `<c-r>` in insert mode.

Comment: In this specific scenario `DO<c-o>p` might be simpler because you don't have to think about which register to choose. You could also use `C<BS><Esc>O<c-o>p` to clean the trailing white space.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution beside the one suggested by FDinoff:

<kbd>D</kbd> at the first slash(cuts the comment until end of line)

And run`:pu!` (put the content above the current line.)